# hyphenate "cutting-edge" & "state-of-the-art" following to-be verbs?

Tags: punctuation

Is hyphenation preferred with "cutting-edge" and "state-of-the-art" when they follow a form of the verb to-be?

Yes or no to the hyphenation below?

The new software was cutting-edge.

The technology is state-of-the-art.

I think the hyphens make for an easier initial read. Do you concur?

Thank you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps the Qs can be merged, but the other post has no satisfactory, canonical answer (the question *per se* may not have one, which is a different matter.)

Comment: It's actually answered as well as is probably possible at the [_“object-oriented” vs “object oriented”_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150055/object-oriented-vs-object-oriented) thread. The above link links to this hard-to-find parallel question. Of course, individual quirks must be checked individually in dictionaries (which may well disagree).

Answer (score 3):

1. Depending on extent and frequency of usage, such phrases acquire a status of their own over time. On a case by case, check if the phrase has dropped the hyphens; and if the words of the phrase moved closer to form a single word, even. Refer to a good dictionary each time.
2. In most instances, a hyphenated version of the phrase is used for the adjective while the noun form may have dropped the hyphen.

See [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cutting-edge):

> *cutting edge* n.  "the party’s campaign began to lose its cutting edge"
> *cutting-edge* adj.  "If you are a scientist, you may have pioneered cutting-edge technology."

And, ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/state-of-the-art?q=state%20of%20the%20art))

> modifier: *He said the new kitchen is much more modern and state of the art, …*

but

> *a new state-of-the-art hospital*

Note that

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Originally, a hyphen would likely have been there; with popular usage, it could have been dropped.

Comment: ..... Note what?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock "a hyphenation-related **error**" you say? :) That was what my answer was all about -- its very purpose. Please re-read and contemplate on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reserve the hyphenation for cases where their use is purely adjectival.

Comment: Not as straightforward, though. Please see the references in my answer.