# Confusion regarding the use of peer-review vs peer review

Tags: word-choice, grammar, hyphenation

In an academic paper, I need to use the term **peer-review** many times. However, not 100% sure when to include hyphen. Normally, I do not use hyphen when I say, for example:

> When students participate in peer reviews...

However I include a hyphen in such cases:

> When students participate in peer-review activities...

I wonder if the way I use the hyphen is correct or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to connect a word and a phrase with a hyphen](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/how-to-connect-a-word-and-a-phrase-with-a-hyphen); see also ["object-oriented" vs "object oriented"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150055/object-oriented-vs-object-oriented)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used as a noun, 'peer review' does not require a hyphen. 
However, when used as an adjective, it does necessitate one.
For example:

*When students participate in peer reviews..* (Here, 'peer reviews' is not modifying anything, hence no hyphen required)

*When students participate in peer-review activities..* (Here, 'peer review' is describing the 'activities' in question, hence the hyphen)

In conclusion, the way you're using it is correct.

Comment: Please note that (a) this has been answered on ELU before (though it would be hard for a newer member to find this particular duplicate) (b) more importantly, answers at the duplicate include supporting statements from recognised authorities (which ELU vastly prefers to be the case).

Comment: In fact, the situation seems to be that most people do the opposite of what you claim to be 'necess[ary]'. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peer+review+activities%2Cpeer-review+activities&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeer%20review%20activities%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeer%20-%20review%20activities%3B%2Cc0) seem to show that the incorrect parsing of peer + review + activities is so unlikely that the hyphen is superfluous to requirements here....

Comment: The Wikipedia article at the duplicate thread points out this common 'breaking' of the 'always hyphenate compound pre-modifiers' 'rule'.